# Could not add Access-Control-Allow-Origin to my WCF library Project

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, wcf

I'm trying to understand why this ajax called doesn't work

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/InMotionGIT_NT.Address.Service/AddressService/json/capitalize",
        data: { streetAddress : JSON.stringify(streetAddress) , consumer :  JSON.stringify(consumer)} ,
        datatype: "jsonp",
        success: function (data) {
            $('body').append('<div>'+data.IDblah+' '+ data.prueba+'</div>');
            alert(data.IDblah);
        }
```

The service receive the data is correctly received and the response it's correct. Why am I doing wrong?

I tried adding this property to the ajax called but without success `crossDomain : true`

```
[OperationContract()]
[WebInvoke(Method="GET", RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public string Capitalize(StreetAddress streetAddress,ConsumerInformation consumer)
```

The error that i'm getting it's the common

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load Origin http://localhost:50816 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

**UPDATE**

I tried to add the header to the response by adding the configuracion in my `App.config` file but without success

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I am having the same problem here, how did you solved your isssue? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This link would help: http://enable-cors.org/

You need to add the following headers in your response that is sent back to the client:

//Allow all domains

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

OR

//Allow specific domains

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com:8080 http://foo.example.com`

Comment: Also it should be dataType not datatype. Also after the above try putting the response in script tag if it isn't wrapped on the server

Comment: ok so I Added the configuration to my project but still without send the header to the client i updated my question with my configuracion

Comment: same here, I added that same couple of custom classes and it does hit that logic but the response still does not have the headers.

Answer (score 14):

Put this in the service side of your configuration file

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

It works for me! Thanks!

Comment: Worked for my on both my WCF REST and SOAP web services :)

Answer (score 2):

the solution is to create a file Global.asax

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost");
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, DELETE");

        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same problem when working with my WCF service directly in Visual Studio, in Chrome and Firefox.
I fixed it with the following:

Edit the Global.asax file with below function:

```
            private void EnableCrossDomainAjaxCall()
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, Accept");
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
                }
            }
```

Then call the function from

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       EnableCrossDomainAjaxCall();
    }
```

You can get more information from the following url:

http://blog.blums.eu/2013/09/05/restfull-wcf-service-with-cors-and-jquery-and-basic-access-authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of handling this, which is better for self-hosted services, can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23493495/how-to-include-wcf-custom-headers-in-console-service-host/25620635).

Answer (score 0):

For WCF service you have to develop new behavior and include it in the endpoint configuration:

1. Create Message Inspector

   ```
       public class CustomHeaderMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
       {
           Dictionary<string, string> requiredHeaders;
           public CustomHeaderMessageInspector (Dictionary<string, string> headers)
           {
               requiredHeaders = headers ?? new Dictionary<string, string>();
           }

           public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
           {
               return null;
           }

           public void BeforeSendReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
           {
               var httpHeader = reply.Properties["httpResponse"] as HttpResponseMessageProperty;
               foreach (var item in requiredHeaders)
               {
                   httpHeader.Headers.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
               }           
           }
       }
   ```
2. Create Endpoint Behavior and use Message Inspector to add headers

   ```
       public class EnableCrossOriginResourceSharingBehavior : BehaviorExtensionElement, IEndpointBehavior
       {
           public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
           {

           }

           public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
           {

           }

           public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
           {
               var requiredHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>();

               requiredHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
               requiredHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Request-Method", "POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
               requiredHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,Content-Type");

               endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new CustomHeaderMessageInspector(requiredHeaders));
           }

           public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
           {

           }

           public override Type BehaviorType
           {
               get { return typeof(EnableCrossOriginResourceSharingBehavior); }
           }

           protected override object CreateBehavior()
           {
               return new EnableCrossOriginResourceSharingBehavior();
           }
       }
   ```
3. Register new behavior in web.config

   ```
   <extensions>
    <behaviorExtensions>        
               <add name="crossOriginResourceSharingBehavior" type="Services.Behaviours.EnableCrossOriginResourceSharingBehavior, Services, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />        
     </behaviorExtensions>      
   </extensions>
   ```
4. Add new behavior to endpoint behavior configuration

   ```
   <endpointBehaviors>      
    <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
     <webHttp />
      <crossOriginResourceSharingBehavior />
    </behavior>
   </endpointBehaviors>
   ```
5. Configure endpoint

   ```
   <endpoint address="api" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" contract="Service.IServiceContract" />
   ```

Comment: I also facing the same issue and I used you code and now i m facing below error

"The type 'Services.Behaviours.EnableCrossOriginResourceSharingBehavior, Services, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral' registered for extension 'crossOriginResourceSharingBehavior' could not be loaded"